# PHP Date function for current year not working right?

Tags: php, date

Ok so I was trying to have a form dropdown menu autoselect the current date without too much javascript coding, so I got the code below (it doesn't autoselect, but it does include the current date as the first options). The year wasn't showing up first like it was supposed to. I did the same for day and month, and those 2 worked perfectly, yet when I had the same code, except days / months in place of years (mday and mon inside brackets), the first year selection wasn't appearing. I'm guessing the problem is the part inside two instances of [$t['year']]. The rest of the code is functioning fine, but I just included it in case I missed something about it (I also tried replacing all years with the last their respective last 2 digits but same result).

```
<?php
$t = getdate(time()); 
$year = array(1 =>'2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027', '2028', '2029', '2030'); 

echo '&nbsp Year <select name="year" >'; 
echo '<option value="\" . $t[\'year\'] . \"">' . $year[$t['year']] . '</option>'; 
foreach( $year as $key => $value ) { 
    echo "<option value = \"$key\">$value</option>"; 
} 
echo '</select>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date('Y')`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
$t = getdate(time()); 
$year = array('2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027', '2028', '2029', '2030'); 

echo '&nbsp Year <select name="year" >'."\n"; 
echo '<option value="' . array_search(date('Y'),$year) . '">' . date('Y') . '</option>'."\n"; 
foreach( $year as $key => $value ) { 
    echo "<option value = \"$key\">$value</option>\n"; 
} 
echo '</select>'."\n";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/7h2MnxzC

This will also select just the one value in the `select`, so you don't need two:

```
<?php
$t = getdate(time()); 
$year = array('2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027', '2028', '2029', '2030'); 
$c_year = date('Y');

echo '&nbsp Year <select name="year" >'."\n"; 
foreach( $year as $key => $value ) { 
    echo "<option".($c_year == $value?' selected="true"':'')." value = \"$key\">$value</option>\n"; 
} 
echo '</select>'."\n";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/uGx6zoyn

Comment: I've already read up on all of that.  It doesn't necessarily work in my situation.  I'm trying to get the year's equivalent to 'mday' and 'mon', which is supposed to be 'year'...

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure why you're doing it that way, but that will work.

Comment: After spending lots of time verifying what the OP wanted, I will sadly +1 this.  I am tired of having to constantly refer people to the php.net manual! **Edit:** Oh good, there was something to add!

Comment: hmm, sorry, I'm still a novice to this.  Didn't know to use array_search.  Thanks :)

Comment: @user987026 - I added a second option which is probably better.

Comment: @user987026 - The PHP manual is very good, one of the best. And PHP has many, many, *many* functions for low-level things like this.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I did do a few hours worth of searching but I guess I should have looked more closely at the manual.  Thanks for the 2nd option btw, just what I was trying to make :D

Comment: @user987026 - No worries; I've been doing PHP for, let's see..., eight years, and I still come across useful functions I didn't know about that had been there all along. I was more or less just passing on information. However, you can typically find very good examples there. You just need more seasoning to know how to look.

Answer (score 2):

```
$years = range(2000, 2030);
$cur_year = date('Y');

echo '<select name="year">';
foreach($years as $year)
    if($year == $cur_year)
        echo "<option selected>$year</option>"; 
    else
        echo "<option>$year</option>";
echo '</select>';
```